# Android : Calling notifyDataSetChanged in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, notify

I'm debugging some open source email client in android right now but I have problem regarding the message status(read and unread). Whenever the client receives a new message and check mail, all the read messages become unread again. I has a customize class extending BaseAdapter. Part of my tracing is I invoked notifyDataSetChanged in onResume. My question is, how would I know that by notifyDataSetChanged really changes the view. I put logs in bindView and getView to know if it really passes once I call notifyDataSetChanged but the logs didn't show up. Does that mean it didn't call the adapter to set a new view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to call `invalidate()` and `invalidateViews()` in the instance of list.